# Reserving static IP for existing Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network, preserve

I have created 3 virtual machines which are already in operation and I forgot to first assign a static IP at time of creation. I am now encountering some issues when I am trying to do this.

I have created a reserved IP using the following powershell:

```
New-AzureReservedIP “dmz-live” –Label “be-dmz-ip” –Location “North Europe”
```

Following this post http://prmdbaora.blogspot.in/2015/06/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none.html I tried to delete the VM and reassign but when I use the following code:

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "be-dmz" -InstanceSize "Standard_D11" –ImageName "be-dmz-be-dmz-0-201508100952090393" | New-AzureVM -ServiceName "be-dmz" –ReservedIPName " be-dmz-ip " -Location "CloudVNET”
```

I am getting an error:

```
New-AzureVMConfig : Must specify MediaLocation or set a current storage account using Set-AzureSubscription.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureVMConfig -Name "be-dmz" -InstanceSize "Standard_D11" -ImageName "be-dmz ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureVMConfig], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.NewAzure
VMConfigCommand
```

I have confirmed that the name of the disk is correct, after deleting the cloud service this disk was present but when I tried to run the command it deleted the disk and it is no longer showing in the list of disks

I want to add these machines to a virtual network called "CloudVNET". Can anyone give me a pointer as to what I am doing wrong here please and how I can go about assigned these reserved IPs to the machines

Comment: Have you set the storage account name like the error suggests?

Comment: I have now set the storage account but now my error is stating that it cannot find the reserved IP although when I list reserved IPs it is found, I have tried using the reservedIP name and the label but neither are working

Comment: you have a space at the begin and at the end of your reserved ip name " be-dmz-ip "